# for loop over two variables in parallel

Tags: r

I'm looking for doing a loop with two variables at the same time.

let's say I have this df

```
fruits
apple
apple_others
banana
banana_others
orange
orange_others
```

I want to create a subset for each fruits (with just 'apple' & 'apple_others'). Let's say I manually set up `list_a =c('apple','banana','orange')` and `list_b = c('apple_others','banana_others','orange_others')`.

how can I do something like

```
for (i in list_a) & (j in list_b) {
    subset(df, fruits == i | fruits == j)
}
```

to get

```
subset = apple & apple_others
do what I want
-----
subset = banana&banana_others
do what I want
```

A nested loop is not what I'm looking for since it will create

```
subset = apple&apple_others
do what I want
------
subset = apple&banana_others
do what I want
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` :

```
list_a =c('apple','banana','orange')
list_b = c('apple_others','banana_others','orange_others')

Map(function(x, y) {do What I want}, list_a, list_b)
```

For example, if you want to paste the two variables together.

```
Map(function(x, y) paste(x, y), list_a, list_b)

#$apple
#[1] "apple apple_others"

#$banana
#[1] "banana banana_others"

#$orange
#[1] "orange orange_others"
```

---

To use it in `for` loop you can iterate over the index of one of the value.

```
for (i in seq_along(list_a)) {
  print(paste(list_a[i], list_b[i]))
  do What I want
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem is I need to do a 'huge' code (around 15 lines of code) in the {do what I want} to plot different variables. Map() doesn't allow to do that for what I understood.

Comment: You can have as many lines of code as you want inside `Map` in `{}` same as `for` loop. If it is too confusing I updated the answer to include a `for` loop approach.

Comment: Hey, I found a work-around. `for i in range { list_a[i] list_b[i] }`. Thanks for you answer. I'll try it again to understand how this function works.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, very easy answer if lists have the same len :

```
for (i in range_list) { 
list_a[i] 
list_b[i] 
}
```